# How to store data in a dynamic array of structs?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, dynamic-allocation

I have these structs with which I would like to implement a map

```
typedef struct {
    const char *name;
    int number;
}   Entry;

typedef struct {
    int available;
    int guard;
    Entry *entries;
} Map;
```

and code to work to initialise and put elements in it:

```
Map *map_init() {
    Map *res = (Map *) malloc(sizeof(Map));

    res->available = 4;
    res->guard = 0;
    res->entries = (Entry *) malloc(4 * sizeof(Entry));

    return res;
}

int map_put(Map *map, const char *name, int nr) {
    Entry entry;
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < map->guard; ++i) {
        entry = map->entries[i];
        printf("entry (  x , %u) at %p (%p)\n", entry.number, &entry, entry.name);

        if (!strcmp(entry.name, name))        // Segmentation fault here
            return 0;
    }

    entry = map->entries[map->guard++];
    entry.name = name;
    entry.number = nr;

    printf("entry (%s, %u) at %p (%p)\n", entry.name, entry.number, &entry, entry.name);

    return 1;
}
```

when I run my main method

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("Initialising...\n");
    Map *map = map_init();

    printf("Putting...\n");
    map_put(map, "test", 2);
    map_put(map, "some", 1);

    // ...

    free(map->entries);
    free(map);
    return 0;
}
```

I get as output

```
Initialising...
Putting...
entry (test, 2) at 0x7fff50b32a90 (0x10f0cdf77)
entry (  x , 0) at 0x7fff50b32a90 (0x5000000000000000)
Segmentation fault: 11
```

from which I could derive that the segmentation fault is due to the fact that `entry.name` does not point to a string anymore (also the number is lost, but this does not lead to unauthorised memory access). After I set the data in the first invocation of `map_put`, everything seems to be stored in the correct places.

Anyone an idea where these entries could be overwritten or why the values are not stored?

Comment: I recommend you read [this discussion about casting the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
entry = map->entries[map->guard++];
```

Here you ***copy*** the data from the array into the `entry` structure instance. Then you modify the data of `entry` and discard those modifications. The (original) structure data in the array is still unmodified.

That will of course lead to *undefined behavior* when you in the next call to `map_put` use the uninitialized structures in the array.

Either modify the array structure instance directly and increase `map->guard` separately. Or make `entry` a *pointer* and make it point to the array element.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that variable `entry` in `map_put` is not a pointer. It is a structure. So the code

```
entry = map->entries[map->guard++];
entry.name = name;
entry.number = nr;
```

copies the contents of `map->entries[map->guard]` into `entry`. Then you update the fields in `entry` and return from the function.

The correct code looks like this

```
int map_put(Map *map, const char *name, int nr) {
    Entry *entry;  // <-- entry is a pointer
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < map->guard; ++i) {
        entry = &map->entries[i];
        printf("entry (  x , %u) at %p (%p)\n", entry->number, (void *)entry, (void *)entry->name);

        if (!strcmp(entry->name, name))
            return 0;
    }

    entry = &map->entries[map->guard++];
    entry->name = name;
    entry->number = nr;

    printf("entry (%s, %u) at %p (%p)\n", entry->name, entry->number, (void *)entry, (void *)entry->name);

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a major problem in `map_put`. You use a local `Entry`, in which you *copy* entries from the map. But when you later assign value to the local copy, the original entries from the map are left unchanged.

So when you later try to compare the new name to the existing entry, you are comparing it to uninitialized values, which is Undefined Behaviour.

You should use an `Entry *` instead:

```
int map_put(Map *map, const char *name, int nr) {
    Entry *entry;
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < map->guard; ++i) {
        entry = map->entries + i;
        printf("entry (  x , %u) at %p (%p)\n", entry->number, entry, entry->name);

        if (!strcmp(entry->name, name))        // Segmentation fault here
            return 0;
    }

    entry = &map->entries[map->guard++];
    entry->name = name;
    entry->number = nr;

    printf("entry (%s, %u) at %p (%p)\n", entry->name, entry->number, entry, entry->name);

    return 1;
}
```

But that is not all. You just store the address of a string in name. It is fine in this example, because you are actually passing string litteral constants. But if you read strings from standard input or a file, the content of the buffer will be overwritten with each new value. As you only store the address, you will end with all entries pointing to same value: the last one.

IMHO you should comtemplate using `strdup` to store copies of the string - and free them at the end. BTW, as you have an init function to initialize you `Map`, you should build a cleanup one to have all necessary free in one single place.